# 8 gauge wire for 10 gauge

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have about a 20 foot run for the outdoor compressor to my main breaker box. Can I use 8 gauge wire instead of 10 gauge? (because I already have this length and gauge.)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if it's approved for the line voltage and temperature and if connectors (e.g. wire nuts) are sized to fit. A lower gauge number means *heavier* wire, able to carry more current safely, with lower voltage drop for the same  length, so it should be quite safe if fused correctly for 10-gauge.

The reason heavier wire than necessary is not used is to save on the cost of copper, and to avoid difficulty in routing and bending thick wire.

Comment: I thought so. I'll be sure and check the connections too. Thanks!